# How can I send 7 coins in Draw Something?

Tags: draw-something

Does anyone know how my opponent can award 7 coins for guessing correctly? The most I can select for their turn is 3 coins. How do they award seven coins for a single turn?

Comment: You don't have to make a new account to post again.  Also, instead of posting an answer to show your gratitude, you should accept the answer!  Click the green checkmark next to it.  =]

Answer (score 6):

When selecting a word, there is at the bottom an option to select special words. Those words award more than 3 coins.

Comment: They also cost bombs.